# remove_query_arg() on rewrite rule

Tags: pagination, search, rewrite-rules

I'm attempting to add a `Back to Search Results` link which in essence will simply link back to the starting search page - for example `/?s=test`. I've taken a look at the global query vars and do see there is a `paged` query argument available -- which does do the job when the permalink structure is set to the default - for example `/?s=test&paged=2` run through `remove_query_arg(array('paged'))` corectly becomes `/?s=test`. But, when you visit a second page of search results and you use anything but the default permalink structure - it is not removing `page/2` which is what the default pagination structure outputs.

I believe I could just use `$_GET['s']` and append that onto the site URL.. but I figured I'd ask here to see if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_link was what I was looking for.